# Generate new JSESSIONID when on different application server

Tags: java, apache, session, jboss, ejb

I've got a system with multiple jboss (4.2.3) servers behind multiple apache servers.

In the situation where one of the jboss servers goes down we still get users with sessions for those servers coming in, however they "bounce" around the servers due to the application server ID in the JSESSIONID, causing apache to send the request to random servers for each request, resulting in session timeout errors.

My initial thought was to create an interceptor in the application to invalidate the session if we detect that the session is actually for a different server (i.e. session.invalidate())
But that doesn't cause a new JSESSIONID to be generated (even with the fix described here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-4436)

My next idea was to create a valve to do the same job but on the Request instead of the HttpServletRequest, however I can't find the library to add ValveBase to jboss 4.2.3 (and I'm not even certain that valves are supported by 4.2.3)

Is there either:

a) Anything I've missed in getting one of my 2 ideas above to work
or
b) Any better ideas I haven't thought of for solving the problem ? (I would like to cluster the sessions but can't at the moment due to infrastructure problems)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session Stickyness in Apache so it won't switch to other application server until it dies.

Comment: I've already got Session Stickyness turned on, that's the problem, it keeps on trying to stick to the server once it's died, everything's fine until one of the application servers dies.

Comment: That's an expected behaviour